# Kubernetes: How to increase ephemeral-storage

Tags: kubernetes, storage

I have three master nodes with each 80 GB disk size.
Recently I ran into this problem:

```
Normal   Pulling              52s (x2 over 6m17s)  kubelet, 192.168.10.37  pulling image "gcr.io/kubeflow-images-public/tensorflow-serving-1.8gpu:latest"
  Warning  Evicted              8s (x5 over 4m19s)   kubelet, 192.168.10.37  The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage.
```

–> "The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage."

The storage on the execution node looks like this:

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /
tmpfs                     3.9G         0      3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     3.9G         0      3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /opt
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /mnt
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /media
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /home
none                      3.9G      1.5M      3.9G   0% /run
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /etc/selinux
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /etc/logrotate.d
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /usr/lib/modules
devtmpfs                  3.9G         0      3.9G   0% /host/dev
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /host/dev/shm
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /usr/lib/firmware
none                      3.9G      1.5M      3.9G   0% /var/run
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /etc/docker
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /usr/sbin/xtables-multi
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/log
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /etc/hosts
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /etc/hostname
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /usr/bin/system-docker-runc
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/boot2docker
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/kubelet
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /usr/bin/ros
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/rancher
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /usr/bin/system-docker
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /usr/share/ros
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.rancher
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/rancher/conf
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/rancher/cache
devtmpfs                  3.9G         0      3.9G   0% /dev
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1                 7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0181228584d6531d794879db05bf1b0c0184ed7a4818cf6403084c19d77ea7a0/merged
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/655a92612d5b43207cb50607577a808065818aa4d6442441d05b6dd55cab3229/merged
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b0d8200c48b07df410d9f476dc60571ab855e90f4ab1eb7de1082115781b48bb/merged
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f36e7d814dcb59c5a9a5d15179543f1a370f196dc88269d21a68fb56555a86e4/merged
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/842157b72f9155a86d2e4ee2547807c4a70c06320f5eb6b2ffdb00d2756a2662/merged
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cee5e99308a13a32ce64fdb853d2853c5805ce1eb71d0c050793ffaf8a000db9/merged
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/6ee5a7ad205bf24f1795fd9374cd4a707887ca2edd6f7e1b4a7698f51361966c/shm
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/79decf02c3a0eb6dd681c8f072f9717c15ba17fcb47d693fcfa1c392b3aef002/shm
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/acc7d374f838256762e03aea4378b73de7a38c97b07af77d62ee01135cc1377b/shm
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/46cb89b550bb1d5394fcbd66d2746f34064fb792a4a6b14d524d4f76a1710f7e/shm
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/0db3a0057c9194329fbacc4d5d94ab40eb2babe06dbb180f72ad96c8ff721632/shm
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/6c17379244983233c7516062979684589c24b661bc203e6e1d53904dd7de167f/shm
tmpfs                     3.9G     12.0K      3.9G   0% /opt/rke/var/lib/kubelet/pods/ea5b0e7d-18d6-11e9-86c9-fa163ebea4e5/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/canal-token-gcxzd
tmpfs                     3.9G     12.0K      3.9G   0% /opt/rke/var/lib/kubelet/pods/eab6dac4-18d6-11e9-86c9-fa163ebea4e5/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/cattle-token-lbpxh
tmpfs                     3.9G      8.0K      3.9G   0% /opt/rke/var/lib/kubelet/pods/eab6dac4-18d6-11e9-86c9-fa163ebea4e5/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/cattle-credentials
tmpfs                     3.9G     12.0K      3.9G   0% /opt/rke/var/lib/kubelet/pods/5c672b02-18df-11e9-a246-fa163ebea4e5/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/nginx-ingress-serviceaccount-token-vc522
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c29dc914ee801d2b36d4d2b688e5b060be6297665187f1001f9190fc9ace009d/merged
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0591531eb89d598a8ef9bf49c6c21ea8250ad08489372d3ea5dbf561d44c9340/merged
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/c89f839b36e0f7317c78d806a1ffb24d43a21c472a2e8a734785528c22cce85b/shm
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/33050b02fc38091003e6a18385446f48989c8f64f9a02c64e41a8072beea817c/shm
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a81da21f41c5c9eb2fb54ccdc187a26d5899f35933b4b701139d30f1af3860a4/merged
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f6d546b54d59a29526e4a9187fb75c22c194d28926fca5c9839412933c53ee9d/merged
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/7b0f9471bc66513589e79cc733ed6d69d897270902ffba5c9747b668d0f43472/shm
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cae4765e9eb9004e1372b4b202e03a2a8d3880c918dbc27c676203eef7336080/merged
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/81ee00944f4eb367d4dd06664a7435634916be55c1aa0329509f7a277a522909/merged
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/7888843c2e76b5c3c342a765517ec06edd92b9eab25d26655b0f5812742aa790/merged
tmpfs                     3.9G     12.0K      3.9G   0% /opt/rke/var/lib/kubelet/pods/c19a2ca3-18df-11e9-a246-fa163ebea4e5/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-nzc2d
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4d1c7efa3af94c1bea63021b594704db4504d4d97f5c858bdb6fe697bdefff9b/merged
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e10b7da6d372d241bebcf838e2cf9e6d86ce29801a297a4e7278c7b7329e895d/shm
overlay                   7.4G      5.2G      1.8G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/50df5234e85a2854b27aa8c7a8e483ca755803bc8bf61c25060a6c14b50a932c/merged
```

I already tried to prune all docker systems on all nodes and reconfigured and restarted all.

Is it may be connected with the fact that all the volumes have a limit of 7.4 GB?

How can I increase the ephemeral-storage therefore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it may be connected with the fact that all the volumes have a limit of 7.4 GB?

You really have a single volume `/dev/vda1` and multiple mount points and not several volumes with 7.4GB

Not sure where you are running Kubernetes but that looks like a virtual volume (in a VM). You can increase the size in the VM configuration or cloud provider and then run this to increase the size of the filesystem:

- ext4:

  ```
  $ resize2fs /dev/vda1
  ```
- xfs:

  ```
  $ xfs_growfs /dev/vda1
  ```

Other filesystems will have their own commands too.

The most common issue for running out of disk space on the master(s) is log files, so if that's the case you can set up a cleanup job for them or change the log size configs.

Comment: This worked for me, except I used "gparted" to increase the partition size. Mine was a HyperV VM that originally started with 12GB, so I increased the disk size to 64 GB and then increased the partition size to make use of the rest of the disk.